# Matrix theory, use Kronecker delta

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I been stuck on this problem for a while.

Use Kronecker delta to show when $AE_{i,j}$ is equal to $E_{i,j}A$, where $A$ is a square matrix and $E_{i,j}$ is the elementary matrix, that is $1$ on $(i,j)^{th}$ entry and zero elsewhere.

I know the answer as $A$ needs to be zero on all elements except the intersection  where these two meet. I just cant figure out how to show this with the Kronecker delta.

I forgot to say, in the book they refer to 
$E_{i,j}$ $E_{k,l}$ = (delta)(j,k)$E_{i,l}$

I believe the book want the reader to use this in the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an attempt.  Let me know how I do.

$$(AE(i,j))_{lk} = \sum_{m}A_{lm}E(i,j)_{mk}$$
$$ = \sum_{m}A_{lm}\delta_{im}\delta_{jk}$$
$$ = A_{li}\delta_{jk}$$

$$(E(i,j)A)_{lk} = \sum_{m}E(i,j)_{lm}A_{mk}$$
$$ = \sum_{m}\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}A_{mk}$$
$$ = \delta_{il}A_{jk}$$

We require:

$$ A_{li}\delta_{jk} = \delta_{il}A_{jk}$$

Suppose $j = k$ and $i = l$.  Then $A_{ii} = A_{jj}$.

Suppose $j \ne k$ and $i = l$.  Then $0 = A_{jk}$.

Suppose $j = k$ and $i \ne l$.  Then $A_{li} = 0$.

So the off-diagonal terms of $A$ must be $0$.  The $i$'th and $j$'th terms along its diagonal must be equal.

Comment: This is correct, although i believe this is a different way to solve it than the book teach. Thank you, and wow this is a real brain scratcher.   The book teaches also about E(i,j)E(k,l) = (delta)(j,k)E(i,l).  I believe they want the reader to use this in the exercise. I will study your solution and compare

Comment: In words, my solution is brute force.  I write out what each element of the matrix product would be for both $AE(i,j)$ and $E(i,j)A$ and then I set them equal to each other.  Search "index notation for matrix multiplication" if that wasn't clear.  I also used  $E(i,j)_{mk} = \delta_{mi}\delta_{jk}$, which is true because $E(i,j)_{mk}$ is zero unless it is $E(i,j)_{ij}$, when it is one.

Comment: Thank you, the book i am studying is very dry, and each page takes me a long time to comprehend. It is used in bachelor program in mathematics in Stockholms university. Supposed to be a proof based linear algebra course. I used to be enrolled years ago, but dropped out, now i am just trying to study the material on my own.  For some reason multi variable analysis, proof based multivaraible calculus is so much easier for me to comprehend for some reason. Any books or material that can aid my understanding i would love to be introduced too.

Comment: I recommend you focus on something familiar: matrix multiplication.  You know how to multiply matrices (row by column etc.).  But are you comfortable with matrix multiplication in index notation?  This is key.  If not, study that first.  Compare it to the method you already know.  Think about it for a few hours at least.  Practice multiplying three matrices in index notation.  Do not use the same letter more than twice on one side of an equation.  Once all of that makes perfect sense, you are ready to think about matrix products involving $\delta_{ij}$.  That's what worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, yesterday when you wrote your solution it made little sense to me. But after writing it down and expanding on some things it made allot of sense. I think my mind gets confused in how to keep track with all the different labels, but will def practice much more with index notation. I was also able to prove Ei,j Ek,l = (delta)(j,k)Ei,l by inspiration of your solution, so i am making progress.

Answer (score 0):

I will use Einstein's notation and drop the $i,j$ indices of $E$ to avoid confusion.
We have that
$$(AE)_{kl}=A_{kp}E_{pl}=A_{kp}\delta_{pi}\delta_{lj}=A_{ki}\delta{lj}$$
While
$$(EA)_{kl}=E_{kp}A_{pl}=\delta_{ki}\delta{pj}A_{pl}=A_{jl}\delta_{ki}$$
We want them to be equal, i.e.:
$$A_{ki}\delta_{lj}=A_{jl}\delta_{ki}$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you that helps allot.